# Does Google's API KEY require some sort of waiting period before it is operational?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Yesterday, I decided I was going to add a Google map to my website.  Never having embedded  Google map on a website before, I did a Google search and arrived at:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

The tutorial was straightforward and instructed me on how to add the map.  Part of the process involved turning on Google Maps JavaScript API v3 in my Google account.  I did this, and then copied my Browser API key to the test JavaScript and tried to view the html.

For a fraction of a second, the test map appeared on my website and then just as fast as it appeared, it disappeared and was replaced with a javascript alert window appeared informing me that my APIKEY was not valid.

I figured Google didn't like me running the page locally, so I uploaded it to my web server.  No map.

I've tweaked the allowed referrers for my key to all sorts of things such as:

- mydomain.com
- (star).mydomain.com
- (star).mydomain.com/(star)  // (star) is the asterisk -- SO didn't like the symbol
- mydomain.com/index.html

In all cases, I'm informed my key does not work.  At this point, I'm about ready to bag the attempt since having a map on the website is not really that important...but I am curious as to what the problem is?

I've Googled quite a bit and most people that run into issues seem to have problems with the referrer.

While I've been a Gmail user since it was in Beta, I've never used any other Google services for web dev... is there a waiting period I have to go through before the API key becomes active?

Thanks for your insights.

This is the code I am testing with (code from aforementioned Google tutorial):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The only difference is I have substituted 'API_KEY' for my actual API KEY from Google.

Comment: what's t the URL of this file, are you sure that it matches any of the allowed referers? What's the exact error-message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never experienced a waiting period more than a few minutes for a Google Maps API key. Try removing all of your listed referrers. This will allow all referrers to work.

Comment: Hi Rogue, I also tried removing all referrers.  Same behavior (no map, key error).  Strangely, the Google reports seem to reflect my attempt to view the map using my key.

Comment: Have you enabled `Google Maps JavaScript API v3` in the list of APIs in the Developer Console?

Comment: Yes, that is the only API that I currently have enabled (enabled last night).

Comment: Do you require including `?key=`? From what I understand, it is not needed for all functions and if you don't require those functions there should be no issues.

Comment: Just tried it myself using your HTML snippet. Strangely enough, when I used the API key I experienced the issue, but when I removed the API key it worked properly. I have since added the API key back, and the map is continuing to load.

Comment: I tinkered with it for a few more minutes tonight, but still no success. Maybe something is screwed up with my Google account?  Anyways, I opted to use Bing maps.. took 8 minutes and worked on the first try.  Thanks for trying to help/providing feedback :)